# Windows two-way interaction between user-mode app and kernel-mode driver?

Tags: windows, process, kernel, driver

I'm about to write the following interaction:

When there is a process about to start, driver will notify user app and then it will wait for response from the app.
The app will decide whether or not to allow that process to be created normally or terminated immediately, and send its decision back to the driver.
Base on the decision from user app. The driver will then allow or block the process execution.
This has to work for Windows XP - Windows 8.1.

My question is: What is recommended way to notify user-mode app from driver and then make the driver wait for the response?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to have the app start an asynchronous IOCTL to the driver. When the driver wants to notify the app that something happened, it completes the IRP and the IOCTL completes on the app side.